# Java Sidebar Code for Contacts list on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: java, android, contacts, sidebar

The Android Galaxy S4 has  a nice new A to Z sidebar on the right had side of the contacts screen to allow moving through the phone contacts listview alphabetically by touching a letter and scrolling through the contacts list. Does someone know if the complete Java source code for this sidebar is available (from Google, Samsung, etc.) opensource. Thanks Roy Cotton

Answer (score 1):

There is something like contacts app similar but its like IOS style, give a look at this project : https://github.com/thehung111/ContactListView

otherwise there is one more but without alphabatic sidebar.
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/build-a-contacts-application-with-jquery-mobile-the-android-sdk-part-1/

I hope its this what you want looking for.